# In the machine code given , the contents of addresses FF01 and FF02 were translated from which line in the corresponding assembler program given?

Tags: assembly, machine-learning

In the machine code given , the contents of addresses FF01 and FF02 were translated from which line in the corresponding assembler program given ?

Assembler code:

```
dips   equ      12h
leds   equ      11

       org      ff01
loop:  in       dips

       cma

       out      leds    
       cpi      00000000b 
       jnz      loop

       rst      7
       end
```

Machine code :

```
FF01    DB
FF02    12
FF03    2F
FF04    D3
FF05    11
FF06    FE
FF07    00
FF08    C2
FF09    01
FF0A    FF
FF0B    FF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two bytes:

```
FF01    DB
FF02    12
```

are the machine code for the following instruction:

```
loop:  in       dips
```